# Win7 IE11 Get rid of Realtek icon from taskbar

Tags: windows-7

How do I get rid of Realtek Audio Manager icon from the taskbar? I uninstalled it and it came back.

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution - Delete all registry files related to Realtek Audio
   Manager.
2. Solution - Remove all it's temporary files.
3. Solution - Use **Notification Area Icons** to hide it icon.

Thanks!